# How to change password in Remote desktop?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I have to change my password in remote desktop and I am not getting the option to change password.

I tried with Ctrl + Alt + Delete, it working for local desktop but not for remote.

I also tried with Onscreen keyboard too.

Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>END</kbd>

The above can be used in RDP sessions inc Hyper-V Manager connections

Answer (score -2):

In vmWare environment or VirtualBox

*CTRL + ALT + INSERT*

Or if you have vmwaretools installed: In the menu VM - send ctrl + alt + del

Comment: I RDP into an VirtualBox Windows 10 environment and this doesn't work. The other answer provided does work.